# C on Windows vs Linux - differences

Tags: c, linux, gcc, window

This code works on Windows (Visual studio), but on Linux GCC, it produces incorrect results. Can someone spot the issues? What could work differently on linux vs windows?

Is there a way of compiling this on Linux? I would rather get it working with GCC, so if you can help me spot the issues in the code that will act differently on Linux, that will be great. Thanks -

returning like this: 
        char output[8];
        char *x = output;
        return x;

Comment: You can't seriously expect a free review of that amount of code, with such vague "description" of the problem?!

Comment: Where is the sample input file? What is the expected output? What is you actually got?

Comment: Thanks Lee, input would be simple assembly code: move ax, bx and output should be: 89 d8 (hex) or in binary, it would be: 10001001 11011000

Comment: Have you tried to debug ? And also try to compile it with GCC on windows too...

Comment: In addition to the answer below, why do you store opcodes as strings and not as ints ?

Comment: @Michael, because I don't know how. But at this point, I want to focus on getting it working on Linux with GCC. I will make improvements later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you have plenty of code that returns pointers to local arrays, which is not allowed and will cause undefined behavior when those pointers are de-referenced later. If that code works in Windows, you're just being lucky since the code is not valid.

The two typical solutions are:

1. Have the caller pass in a pointer (and `size_t` length value to prevent overwrite, of course!) to string space where the called function is allowed to work.
2. Dynamically allocate new memory for the string inside the function and return that. It becomes the caller's responsibility to `free()` that memory when it's no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of pointer, can I allocate memory and return that? What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

```
        char output[8];
        char *x = output;
        return x;
```

This is something you are doing in a lot of places of your program (here in `asciiToBin`) and that invokes undefined behavior. You are returning the address of the first element of an array that is declared with automatic storage. When you return from a function, the objects with automatic storage are destroyed and accessing them invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would you suggest to avoid this issue?

Comment: @user3530178 for example, you can just pass the output array (through a pointer) to the function

Comment: Thanks @ouah, I will try to make that change. Please comment if you notice anything else.